# SAPUI5: Binding Attributes of XMLModels

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

How is this done in OpenUI 5 / SAPUI5?
given the following

```
<MainNavigation>
    <Link>
      <property name="Name">Clinical Overview</property>
      <property name="command">showTeachingPoints</property>
      <property name="autoSelect">true</property>
    </Link>
    <Link>
      <property name="command">showDevices</property>
      <property name="Name">Equipment</property>
    </Link>
</MainNavigation>
```

And trying to fill out the `text` property for the following:

```
<tnt:SideNavigation expanded="true" itemSelect="onItemSelect">
  <tnt:NavigationList id="sideMenu" items="{/MainNavigation/Link}">
    <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{property/[@name='Name']/text()}" />
  </tnt:NavigationList>
</tnt:SideNavigation>
```

The goal should be to display the Name of each property (so Clinical Overview, Equipment, etc...) but the query is not working.

Also I've tried:

```
{property/[@name='Name']/text()}
{property/[name='Name']/text()}
{property/['@name='Name'']/text()}
{property[@name='Name']/text()}
```

The only way that's worked has been

`{property}`

However that will only display whatever is first in the collection of property nodes. I want to know how to get at a specific node since I want to use the other nodes for different purposes (default selection, function callback names, etc...)

edited to clarify:
The list should contain:

```
Clinical Overview
Equipment
```

Using `{property/@name}` the list would be:

```
Name
command
```

Granted this is not what I'm looking for but it shares the same problem as `{property}` in that it returns only the first item under `<Link>` when I may want the second or third.

This xpath query works in other places `/UI/MainNavigation/Link/property[@name='Name']/text()` and I would just like to how to translate that into OpenUI.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<tnt:SideNavigation expanded="true" itemSelect="onItemSelect">
  <tnt:NavigationList id="sideMenu" items="{/MainNavigation/Link}">
    <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{property/@name}" />
  </tnt:NavigationList>
</tnt:SideNavigation>
```

More info in the docs about [Binding Path Syntax for XML Models](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.20/#docs/guide/a53e71d85fae4d0887a8b58431197a27.html#loioa53e71d85fae4d0887a8b58431197a27).

> For attributes, a special selector using the "@" character exists and "text()" can be used to reference the content text of an element. Lists are referenced by using the path to the multiple element.

BR Chris

Comment: I have read through that link you provided before which is where I thought I could do xpath queries, and I had already tried `{property/@name}` as one of my initial attempts but it returns the value of the name attribute (so I would see `Name` in all of my fields), which is not what I want. Additionally `{property/@name/text()}` I thought might have done the trick since it would be similar to a regular xpath query, but it returns blank text. I edited my original question to try and better explain what I'm looking for.

Comment: Alright. Thats just not possible with regular binding syntax... You‘ll have to edit your data before. Should be easy with jQuery.